# Get mobile phone specific by c# mvc web

Tags: javascript, c#, android, iphone

Please help me.
I have a website that run on mobile phone browser. I need to know which device it running on. Example :

vendor : Samsung - model: GT-I8552 - version : Galaxy Win - platform : Android - 
version : 4.1.2.

I use C# and javascript. "navigator.userAgent" doesn't have enough data i need. Specially the phone name such as Iphone 6 or Galaxy S6.

Comment: Could you paste some snippet please ?

Comment: This might help - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/mobile-phone-detection-brand-model-browser-etc

Comment: Thank you @LiamB, but I want an example get direct phone name : iphone 6 or Galaxy S6

Comment: @flafoux I try "navigator.userAgent" in js but it doesn't show phone name

Comment: Have a look in the link posted, several of the services do that.